# The value x assigned to y is never used in a switch statement?

Tags: java, android

```
public void operationOnClick(View view){
        int operandOneValue = Integer.valueOf(operandOne.getText().toString());
        int operandTwoValue = Integer.valueOf(operandTwo.getText().toString());
        int resultValue = 0;
        Button op = (Button)view;
        String operation = op.getText().toString();

        switch(operation){
            // now i change the keyword 'return' with 'break'
            // i got the problem.
            case "+" : resultValue = operandOneValue+operandTwoValue;return;
            case "-" : resultValue = operandOneValue-operandTwoValue;return;
            case "*" : resultValue = operandOneValue*operandTwoValue;return;
            case "/" : resultValue = operandOneValue/operandTwoValue;return;
        }
        result.setText(String.valueOf(resultValue));
    }
```

The value operandOneValue+opearndTwoValue assigned to 'resultValue' is never used?I can't figure out the error?

Comment: You `return` right after assigning to `resultValue`, so nothing after that part is run.

Comment: Please post code, not a picture of code. You probably want break statements in the switch, not returns.

Comment: Please help me? How can i delete the question?

Comment: restored the original `return` instructions in code - this is what the code looked like when the question was posted. You shouldn't edit the original code to fix it, or it will invalidate the comments and answers that other users kindly provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your switch statement, replace every `return;` with `break;` which is the signal to break out of the switch, but the rest of the code will run. When you write `return` within a void method, when its reached it means you are breaking out of the method itself so no code past it will be read. In this case, if your switch cases match, you will never reach the `setText` method.

Answer (score 1):

Method's return type is `void` and you returned from inside `case` so statement below are inaccessible. Try like below.

```
        String output="";
        switch(operation) {
            case "+":
                output=(operand1+operand2).toString();
                break;
            case "-":
                output=(operand1-operand2).toString();
                break;
            case "*":
                output=(operand1*operand2).toString();
                break;
            case "/":
                output=(operand1/operand2).toString();
                break;
        }
        result.setText(output);
```

Comment: Thank you, That is a silly question, sorry for asking this type of question.